# Linux word search using grep

Tags: grep

I want to search a file in which there any words which contain alphanumeric words (i.e. words that have both combination of alpha and numeral)

I have tried using different grep combinations but not able to find the exact result I want to achieve

for example if I have a file that contains multiple lines

```
asbcd acblk54 lkasdfn
098213 102938 091283 
aalk adsf adf
lkjas 0098324 0980 assdf
alkj30lkl 093adflkj 0lkdsf094
```

since lines 1 and 5 contain words which are alphanumeric only two lines should be filtered. how can I achieve this using grep.(line 2 contains numerals only, line 3 contains alpha only, line 4 contains words that are either alpha or numeral but not combination of both)

Comment: All lines only contain alphanumeric words. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Muhammad, I think you mean to search for lines containing words, that have both letters and numerals, right? As Dominique points out in another comment, letters and numerals are "alphanumeric", so "asbcd" and "098213" are also alphanumeric words, even though one only contains letters ("ALPHAbetical") and the other only contains numbers (NUMerical). Please update your question to clarify this. Thanks, and have a nice day :-)

Comment: Thanks Martin, I have updated my query and mentioned it more clearly

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Comment: i tried using `grep [[:alnum:]] sample.txt` but it did not give the desired result also tried some other combinations of wildcards and regex but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are interested in is a grep that matches full words. So you need the `-w` option:

> **`-w, --word-regexp`:** Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words.  The test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character.  Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.  This option has no effect if `-x` is also specified.
>
> <sub>**source: `man grep`**</sub>

The regex you search for uses indeed `[[:alnum:]]` but you have to ensure that it has both a `[[:alpha:]]` and a `[[:digit:]]`. A word containing both must thus have a sequence `[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]` or `[[:digit:]][[:alpha:]]`. The regex you are after is thus: `[[:alnum:]]*([[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]|[[:digit:]][[:alpha:]])[[:alnum:]]*`

The following grep will do the matches:

```
$ grep -w -E '[[:alnum:]]*([[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]|[[:digit:]][[:alpha:]])[[:alnum:]]*' file
```

Comment: Thanks for the details I did find about the `-w option for grep` however I wasn't expecting such a long regex for this pattern search. This works exactly as I needed.